# Setting up a libgdx project with intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, libgdx

I tried to set up a project with libgdx, but I get a errror if I hopen it in intellij. I deleted the project again and tried to set up a new one, but it changed nothing. I hope someone can help me.

[Here are some screenshots: 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGpcp.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6cbl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Select the JDK version, compatible with Gradle in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Gradle JVM**. Try JDK of lower than 16 versions.